# Avoid duplicating deployment code for two branches in BitBucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following BitBucket pipeline script which preserves some files, does deployment and restores the files.

As shown this applies to the `master` branch. For the `development` branch I need exactly the same script. The only difference is that `deployment: production` will become `deployment: development` since I need other environment variables, set in BitBucket.

I've looked into https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/ for YAML anchors to make this script as a function. But couldn't get it to work.

Is there a way to avoid this part being copied for the development branch?

```
  branches:
master:
  - step:
      name: Deployment to production
      deployment: production
      trigger: manual
      script:
        - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:1.0.1
          variables:
            USER: $DOMAIN
            SERVER: $SERVER
            REMOTE_PATH: '~/public/prod'
            LOCAL_PATH: 'dist/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define steps:
[image]

You have to define a custom pipeline like below:

[image]

And within your step:

[image]

We have it working in our environment.